# Unboxing not able to understand

Tags: java, unboxing

```
public class AccountManager {

    priavte Map accountTotals = new HashMap();
    private int retirementFund;

    public int getbalance(String accountName) {
        **Integer Total = (Integer) accountTotals.get(accountName);
        if(total == Null)
            total = Integer.valueof(0);
        return total.intValue;**
    }

    public void setBalance (string accountName, int amount) {
        accountTotals.put(accountname, Integer.valueof(amount));
    }
}
```

I can replace the highlighted code with two of the them to perform it:

1:

```
int Total = accountTotals.get(accountName);
if(total == null)
    total = 0;
return total;
```

2:

```
Integer total = accountTotals.get(accountName);
if(total == null)
    total = 0;
return total;
```

3:

```
return accountTotals.get(accountName);
```

Can someone tell me which two of the above 3 I should replace with the highlighted code ? And why ?

Thanks!!

Comment: Why don't you try all three options with a Java compiler and see which work?

Comment: Yeah I will try doing that

Comment: What does it have to do with generics?

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look like this:

```
public class AccountManager {
    private Map<String, Integer> accountTotals = new HashMap<>();
    private int retirementFund;

    public int getbalance(String accountName) {
        Integer total = accountTotals.get(accountName);
        if(total == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        return total;
    }

    public void setBalance (String accountName, int amount) {
        accountTotals.put(accountName, amount);
    }
}
```

Aside from many typos in the source code, here is some explanation:

- Use the generic version of map: `Map<String, Integer>`. This will give you typesafety both when you put or get data from the map.
- Unfortunately, Java generics don't work with primitive types. Therefore the map must contain boxed `Integer` instances.
- On the other hand, this allows you to use the `total == null` condition to check whether the value is in the map or not. That's why you need to use `Integer total = accountTotals.get(accountName)` instead of `int total = accountTotals.get(accountName);`. If the value is not present, the latter would try to unbox the result of `get()` to store it in the `int` variable. But because `null` cannot be unboxed, you would get a `NullPointerException`.
- When returning, you can simply write `return total;`. Even though `total` is of type `Integer` and the result type is `int`, Java will automatically unbox the value. Of course, you can only do this if `total` is not `null`.

Since your question was probably aimed at conversion between `Integer` and `int`, you can see that Java is doing conversions in both directions automatically (boxing: `accountTotals.put(accountName, amount)`, unboxing: `return total`). You just have to keep in mind that only `Integer` can contain `null` and if you try to unbox a `null` value, you'll get `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

int isn't allowed to be null. Integer is allowed to be null. The access from the hashmap can return a null, so the value can't be an int...